# Stored procedures with ODBC through Go/Golang

Tags: stored-procedures, go, odbc, unixodbc

I'm using the ODBC driver from The Brainman. I'm using the generic ODBC syntax, which is to use "CALL" to invoke a Stored Procedure. Here is my code:

```
stmt, stmtErr := db.Prepare("CALL RecordClick (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
if stmtErr != nil {
    fmt.Printf("\nstmtErr: %s", stmtErr)
}
defer stmt.Close()

var aclickid int
stmtRows, stmtRowsErr := stmt.Query(xaid, subtag, r.Referer, requestUserAgent, requestIP, ip, ua, title, description, displayurl, clickUrl, kw, rpc, exid)
if stmtRowsErr != nil {
    fmt.Printf("\nstmtRowsErr: %s", stmtRowsErr)
}
for stmtRows.Next() {
    stmtRows.Scan(&aclickid)
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
stmtRowsErr: sql: converting Exec argument #2's type: unsupported type func() string, a func
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried it with and without curly braces around the CALL XXX (?, ?, ?) part, and it still won't work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The error message looks incomplete, can you post the whole message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `r.Referer` (Type `func`) in `stmt.Query` should be [`r.Referer()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Referer) (Returns type `string`, From [`net/http`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)).

So the line should read:

```
stmtRows, stmtRowsErr := stmt.Query(xaid, subtag, r.Referer(), requestUserAgent, requestIP, ip, ua, title, description, displayurl, clickUrl, kw, rpc, exid)
```

That error is coming from [Line #37 of `convert.go` in the `database/sql` package](http://golang.org/src/pkg/database/sql/convert.go?s=958:1036#L37).

It's telling you that the type conversion for argument #2 (zero indexed) of the SQL query couldn't be converted into the type expected by the SQL engine (In particular the function  `driver.DefaultParameterConverter.ConvertValue(arg)` failed.)

Check the types for each variable in your query with something like:

```
fmt.Printf("%T %T %T %T %T %T %T %T %T %T %T %T %T %T", xaid, subtag, r.Referer, requestUserAgent, requestIP, ip, ua, title, description, displayurl, clickUrl, kw, rpc, exid)
```

and see if any of them are unexpected or incorrect.

Comment: @AllisonA Pretty sure I've seen that error before in my own code :-) It seemed familiar.